# I have a custom Array class and I want to know the data type

Tags: java

I have a class with a data type referenced `Array<?>`. I then have a function that returns an object. When I try to find out the class of the object, I cannot find the type of object it contains. `o.getClass().getName()` returns `manager.constructors.Array` without the datatype `<U>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Comment: That doesn't answer it as I am getting it as an object and I can't cast it to the array without the type.